# incorrect start asyncio script with systemd

Tags: python, python-asyncio, systemd

I have python script with `ioloop` based on `asyncio` which work with web and have some crawlers inside which should start by scheduler. I make new task in `systemd` which start it, but - when script is started on system start only first `coroutine` is started, when I restart task manually - all `coroutines` are started. 
Please see my config below. I tried to set `type = forking`, but on this case task is restarted by `ubuntu`. How should I make config for correct work?

```
[Unit]

Description=Stocks

After=network.target


[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]

ExecStart=/home/user/Projects/stocks/venv/bin/python /home/user/Projects/project/manage.py runserver

Type=simple

Restart=on_failure
```

Comment: It should work the same. Please check the logs (stderr output) of your program (see journalctl) and add some more info regarding your program.

Comment: @Udi What kind of logs? My program is web app based on aiohttp, so I start it like this:        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    resource = prepare_resources(loop, env_type)

    from urls import urls
    from tasks import tasks

    httpserver = HttpServer(urls, resource)
    scheduler = Scheduler(tasks, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/log.txt'))

    loop.run_forever()

Comment: See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs